# How to get the values from php array not matching in mysql database query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have list as a php array.

```
1  
2
3
4
5
```

I want to get the list of elements not satiesfying the mysql query. (i.e. where the mysql do not have the array value matching with desired column of db). 
The db column: db_value suppose has the following.

```
1
3
5
8
```

Here `$output` gives matched query output.

```
1
3
5
```

I need the complement of that.

```
2
4
```

Here is the code I have :

```
<?php
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE db_value="$value";";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $output=$row[db_value];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: show us the values of `$array` and the output of `prinr_r($output);` also, so that we can understand your problem. Also post desired output you want based on those two arrays.

Comment: okay I need to edit then.

Comment: you missed to concatenate `$value`

Comment: Btw, it's generally a bad idea to execute a query inside a loop. The (major) exception is when using prepared statements, which is of course what you should be doing!

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE db_value not in (".implode(",",$array).") ";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

Comment: Yeah @Strawberry , actual query is far more complex and needs to be prepared from various arrays

Comment: @JigarShah okaybut i just want the non matching ones. suppose the statement is correct.

Comment: Ignoring all the php stuff, one approach is to outer join an indexed column of the array items and select only those rows with a NULL match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***1st method***

```
$listArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // our list which is to be match from db

$myArray = implode(",", $listArray); // array to string 

$query = "SELECT * FROM db WHERE db_value NOT IN ($myArray)";
```

**Now `$query` will return you desired output**

> ***2nd Method***

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM db"; // get all from database 

$db_value = array_column($query['db_values']); // suppose $query have database output
```

Now Get different between both array using [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) function

```
$result = array_diff($db_value, $listArray); // gives you desired output
```

Comment: FWIW, I like the second approach

Comment: Thanks NOT IN was the mysql thing I really appreciate.